# Bluetooth LE Disconnects on Pause

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want my bluetooth device to stay connected when the app is not in the main view.  Every time I open the home tab or another app it disconnects.  How do I maintain a connection on pause?  Relevant code is below:

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //Cancel any scans in progress
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStopRunnable);
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStartRunnable);
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(this);
    }

    private Runnable mStopRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            stopScan();
        }
    };

    private Runnable mStartRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startScan();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading more android documentation, I realized I was confusing `onStop()` with `onDestroy()`.  I had a disconnect feature in my `onStop()`.  Once this was removed it remained connected despite me closing the window.